# How to record stereo sound from Line-In in command line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, sound, alsa, ffmpeg

I have plugged my phones into rear Line-In socket of my computer. I want to use it as stereo microphone, I tried this on desktop and it worked.

Now, how can I record sound from it with command line?

For example, if I use `ffmpeg`, I have no means to configure input socket. If I run

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i sysdefault:CARD=MID -t 30 out.wav
```

but records absolutely silent file.

Alsamixer screen is following:

[image]

Areord shows following:

```
$ arecord -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=MID
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, VT1708S Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

**UPDATE**

After I have configured input in `gnome-control-center` it started to work.

[image]

But I don't want to use `GUI` tools, I need command-line-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to record from Line in ALSA, maybe you would hear sound if you select Line as capture device and increase capture level from 0

you could use `arecord` command for recording from ALSA

arecord -f [format] -D hw:card,device -d [duration]

Comment: But how to select source? Sound card has multiple `IN` sockets, rear and front panel. How to select them?

Comment: 'arecord -L' will list sound PCM device. then use 'arecord --device=[PCM NAME]'. see 'man arecord' for additional options

Comment: `arecord -L` output is above. I don't see any microphones and/or line ins there.

Comment: my bad, should have been arecord -l ,or arecord --list-devices. have edited my answer to general arecord command, but need to check intel MID card number (probably hw:0 if is only card) and device number for mic

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the alsamixer capture view, use the left/right arrow keys to move over to "Line" and press the spacebar to activate it as the capture device. That will move the red "CAPTURE" message to Line instead of Front Mic. Make sure to also adjust the Capture gain.